# pandas install issues in gitlab and docker

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, continuous-integration, gitlab

```
Collecting numpy (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading numpy-1.11.1.zip (4.7MB)
Collecting pandas (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading pandas-0.18.1.tar.gz (7.3MB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'numpy' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or download links found for numpy>=1.7.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-8puw9oba/pandas/setup.py", line 631, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 634, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.7.0')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-8puw9oba/pandas/

ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

Trying continuous Integration with gitlab and am running into an issue after pandas has been added as a requirement. when running the pytest the error above happens. the yaml for the gitlab-ci looks like this:

```
pytest:
  image: python:3-alpine
  script:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python -m pytest tests --ignore=tests/test_routes.py

eslint:
  image: node:4.4.7

  cache:
    paths:
    - src/static/node_modules/

  script:
  - cd src/static
  - npm --loglevel=silent install
  - npm --loglevel=silent install gulp -g
  - gulp lint
```

pytest is the one that is failing before it even gets to running the tests

the contents of our requirements.txt are as follows:

```
astroid==1.4.5
blinker==1.4
click==6.3
colorama==0.3.7
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.0
Flask-Login==0.3.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-WTF==0.12
Jinja2==2.8
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.1
MarkupSafe==0.23
passlib==1.6.5
pylint==1.5.5
requests==2.9.1
six==1.10.0
Werkzeug==0.11.4
wrapt==1.10.6
WTForms==2.1
pandas
pyaml
rtyaml
webtest
hypothesis
beautifulsoup4
pytest
```

I attempted manually adding numpy before pandas but got the same result. since it complained about numpy >=1.7.0 I also attempted explicitly telling it that version but that did not resolve the issue either. Is there anything I am missing in this configuration that would be causing this problem?

Comment: The problem is not pandas. The install of numpy is not working, because the download fails. I don't have any tips regarding this certificate-stuff though. But you should limit your search to this line ```Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)```. Maybe something is wrong with openSSL.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is unable to verify the certificate. You need to manually say which certificate it should use to verify it.

This should work:

```
pip --cert /etc/ssl/certs/DigiCert_High_Assurance_EV_Root_CA.pem install -r requirements.txt
```